# Search for names in a hard-coded list of contacts

Tags: java, beginner, strings, array

I am currently taking a class at my local community college for java programming as well as trying to learn as much as I can on my own time. I would like your opinion on a program I wrote that would display any results matching a user inputted search term. It works, but I feel like it could be written better or even be made more effective, I'm not sure as I am still kind of new to Java. Could you please let me know if I am doing anything wrong like bad coding habits, doing things that are more easily done with better code, or suggest anything you think I should improve upon.

```
package controller;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PhoneListDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        promptUser();

    }
    public static void promptUser() {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a name or characters to search for: ");
        String userSearch = keyboard.nextLine();
        keyboard.close();
        searchAndDisplay(userSearch);
    }
    public static void searchAndDisplay(String userSearch) {

        String[] names = {"Harrison, Rose", "James, Jean", "Smith, William", "Smith, Brad"};
        String[] phone = {"555-2234", "555-9098", "555-1785", "555-9224"};

        for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {

        if(names[i].toLowerCase().contains(userSearch.toLowerCase())) {

            System.out.println(names[i] + ":  " + phone[i]);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Structure

It surprises me that `promptUser()` also performs the search.  Amongst other things, this makes it harder for you to test the prompting, and it makes it harder to re-use the function for something else.

I would expect `main()` to look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String search_string
         = promptUser("Enter a name or characters to search for: ");
    searchAndDisplay(search_string);
}
```

We need to modify `promptUser()` to accept an argument and return a value:

```
public static String promptUser(String prompt) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(prompt);
    String userSearch = keyboard.nextLine();
    keyboard.close();
    return userSearch;
}
```

I hope you see how it has become more reusable.

## Data structure

We would like to be able to separate the search and display parts of `searchAndDisplay()` (because one day, we'll want to search and update, or search and remove).  That's hampered at the moment because each record is scattered across two lists (and we have a weakness that the two lists need to be kept aligned with each other).

Instead, it will be easier to work with a single list of records.  Let's define a `Record` structure that looks something like:

```
public class Record
{
    String name;
    String phone;
}
```

Now, if we have a list of `Record`, we can have a `search()` function that returns a `Record` and a `display()` function that accepts a record and prints it.  I'll let you fill in the rest of `Record` - you'll want at least a constructor, and probably accessors and a `bool matches(String substring)`.

## String comparison

Comparing strings by converting both to lower case usually works for English names, but less well in other languages.  For example, it will prevent `AMELIE` from matching `Amélie` in French (where accents are not usually kept on upper-case words), and it will miss `Groß` when searching for `GROSS`.  There are a couple of Stack Overflow answers that address this (and probably better than my very rusty Java knowledge):

- [How to check if a String contains another String in a case insensitive manner in Java?](//stackoverflow.com/q/86780)
- [Case-insensitive storage and unicode compatibility](//stackoverflow.com/q/6991038)

Beware that there are quite a few bad answers on those questions, mostly recommending `toLower()` or `toUpper()` as you have now.

You probably want something like

```
    Pattern search_re = Pattern.compile(userSearch, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.LITERAL | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
    for (int i = 0;  i < names.length;  i++) {
        if (p.matcher(name).find()) {
            System.out.println(names[i] + ":  " + phone[i]);
        }
    }
```

(where `Pattern` is `java.util.regex.Pattern` - you'll want to `import` that).

Obviously you'll need to adapt that a little once you're storing `Record` objects rather than separated names and phones.

Comment: I'm impressed I learned a lot about string matching from this answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! this was very informative as well as very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can [replace traditional loops](http://www.deadcoderising.com/2015-05-19-java-8-replace-traditional-for-loops-with-intstreams/) with an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) and a [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) using lambdas.  It's up to you if you find this more readable and better to understand (for me: *yes* ^_^)

```
Optional hasValue = IntStream.range(0, names.length).filter(i -> names[i].equalsIgnoreCase(userName)).findFirst();
if (hasValue.isPresent()){
    System.out.println(names[hasValue.get()] + ":  " + phone[hasValue.get()]);
}
```

NOTE: this solution lets you find the **first** match; any further matches are not shown (but *could* be shown, with a slight modification).

---

#### Something totally different:

You're not using any object-orientated approach but an procedural approach. Maybe you want some hints about that.

- use a class for a your input handler, maybe `InputHandler`
- provide a method for the `InputHandler` to read from the command line, like `InputHandler.readFromCommandLine`
- use a class for your address, maybe a `PhoneBook`
- define a method for the `PhoneBook` that lets you find entries

  - by name `PhoneBook.findByName(String name)`
  - by number `PhoneBook.findByNumber(String number)`
- create a class for an address where you can put all data `Address`
- use interfaces...

Your code could look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final PhoneBook phoneBook = new PhoneBook();
    InputHandler inputHandler = new CommandLineInputHandler();
    String searchTerm = inputHandler.readFromCommandLine("Enter a name or characters to search for:");
    Address address = phoneBook.findByName(searchTerm);
    System.out.println(address);
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to change the search from a "contains" to an "is equal" kind of match?  You didn't draw attention to *why* that's better.

Comment: @TobySpeight as written above i wantet to point that you can use Streams instead of traditional loops...

Answer (score 0):

The only tip I have is you could just set your `userSearch` term `toLowerCase()` once so you don't have to do it on every comparison.

```
  String userSearchTerm = userSearch.toLowerCase();
  if(names[i].toLowerCase().contains(userSearchTerm)) {
                System.out.println(names[i] + ":  " + phone[i]);
}
```

Comment: i think it would be even more suitable to use `String.equalsIgnoreCase` so you don't have to do **any** conversions....

Comment: @Martin, `String` doesn't provide a `containsIgnoreCase()` method, but see [my answer](/a/187941) for a suggestion.